# Google Maps Api lat/long key is changing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have google maps integrated in my website. The user is able to create bus routes on the map and save these routes. Now I have encountered that it stopped working because of the following reason: the key of lat/long changes after some time. So a week ago the key is *.A/.F* and now it is changed to *.G/.K.*
Is google changing this in its API for a reason? How could I fix this problem so it would not happen, are there API settings?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I saw that you also had given the answer there

Comment: This question has been asked many times. I answered [an early example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210836/google-maps-ya-za-and-a) too.

Comment: I am very sorry, I am like you and don't like duplicate questions. In the last couple of years of using stackoverflow I have only asked two questions, for all the other questions the answers were already there, and for this question also. So I did search, but could not find, the reason is that the same problems asked before are like: 'Google maps Ya, Za and $a' or 'get current latlng bounds?' which do not really state the problem that I had. Because I already realized that the key changed and now I understand why. THANKS EVERYONE